# Hide a specific post from a page template

Tags: posts, templates, page-template

I am trying to hide a specific post from a page template? Does anyone have experience with this, would prefer to not have to use a plugin. Was thinking of using wp_post ID but am unsure of how to go about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the using **'post__not_in' => array(ID),** is more along the lines I was thinking of:

```
    $args=array(
        'cat' => 12, // Make the free-slots cat id
        'post__not_in' => array(111)
        'showposts' => $show_posts_number,
    );
```

Comment: change showposts to posts_per_page but the rest would be fine but it depends on your exact needs as your question is very, very light in detail e.g. are you pulling all posts into a template?

Comment: Yes all posts from category 12. And thank you for reminding me showposts is deprecated..

Answer (score 1):

At the top of [the loop](https://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop) in your **page.php** of your theme. Add the following condition:

```
if (get_the_ID()==$my_id) {
   exit;
}
```

Comment: Can't see how this will work, would this not stop loop once this ID is found? Any posts after this would not appear..

Comment: @James, then use `continue` instead of `exit`.

Comment: look at my answer below, what are your thoughts?